# Cannot edit categories in Magento after updating to 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

After updating from Magento 1.6 to 1.7, I cannot edit categories on the production server anymore.

Seems to be the ajax POST URLs are broken:

While ajax calls are working fine on the local machine like:

```
http://local.my-domain.de/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/fcc2335e931e8ec4236be7da67156087/id/7/?isAjax=true
```

they're getting messed up into

```
http://my-domain.de/index.php/admin/catalog_category/edit/key/1ac1f1e5f75e665a2fd06eca4569d662/?admin%2Fcatalog_category%2Findex%2Fkey%2F1ed297c236a0c9df5530952aaf7e0618%2F=id/7/&isAjax=true
```

on the production server, causing the ajax call for editing a category to stop working.

Comment: I assume you've flushed all caches, combined CSS/JS etc?

Comment: yep, definitely double- and triple-flushed... didn't seem to help :/

Comment: Do you use combined Javascript?

Comment: Re upload /js/ and /skin/adminhtml.  Make sure you delete/replace the folders so that it isn't some kind of leftover.

Comment: apart from files beloning to extensions, i have deleted everything in those folders and re-uploaded them, but same problem still.

Comment: You could try reuploading /app/design/adminhtml, why avoid replacing extensions, do you not use the same extensions in your test environment?  Look at page source, specifically the #page:left node and the <script> child tag.  Do you see the same url's?

Comment: You could also try making the last RewriteRule "RewriteRule .* index.php [L,B]"

Comment: seems to append the path token as parameters... Updating the files & rewrite rule unfortunately didn't help.

Comment: (i was replacing the folders with downloaded magento package) it's the same code for local & production.

Comment: Are you not changing the domain/subdomain in the database prior to actually loading a page? (core_config_data WHERE path = 'web/unsecure/base_url' OR path = 'web/secure/base_url')

Comment: I'm changing the base_url when fetching the live DB to local (with a shell script and it's the only change to the DB)

Comment: Have you done basic things like, restarting apache, or even rebooting the server just as a hail mary?  I'd suggest editing index.php to also error_log() a variety of $_SERVER variables to to try to figure out if it is happening inside or outside of PHP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encountered this exact error on Magento CE 1.7.0.2 after switching to Nginx 1.4.2 from Apache 2.2.

In your server (Vhost) file, change the `@handler` definition according to the following:

```
location @handler { 
    # rewrite ^(.*) /index.php?$1 last;
    rewrite / /index.php;
}
```

And add the following definition for `php` (in addition to any others you might have):

```
location ~ \.php/ { 
    rewrite ^(.*\.php)/ $1 last;
}
```

That solved the problem for me. Full credit to @isawk: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/303318/#t421375 for the original answer.

Comment: Do you perhaps have a fully working NGINX config? I'm having problems with the default Magento one.

Comment: @Jon Koops Hi Jon, this dood has a complete working example: http://twincreations.co.uk/vhost-configuration-to-host-magento-on-nginx/

Comment: @JonKoopsthanks for pointing this out - i don't use magento anymore, so i couldn't tell...

Comment: This fixed the issue for me on CE 1.5, also.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

As this seems to have to do with some strange server setting in our hosting environment, here's the workaround to somehow fix this:

Copy `/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php`

to `/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php`

an change line 997 from

```
if ($query) {
```

to

```
if ($query && strpos($query, 'catalog_category') === false ) {
```

Comment: Obviously this will work.  But I feel like it is just a little quick patch rather than an actual answer.  Before too long this is going to look like ($query && (strpos($query, 'catalog_category') === false || strpos($query, 'catalog_product_simple') === false || strpos($query, 'cms_page') === false ......)

Comment: This is just a hack around a bigger issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any rewrite rules in your .htaccess file that could be modifying the URL?  It looks like an HTML encoded category link is being added into your URL.

Comment: i'm not using this magento version anymore, so i can't say... but thanks :9

Answer (score 0):

When you update magento version and everything is working fine and as expected but the catalog/category. when you not able to edit/delete categories from Admin Panel and check your ajax request in console.

**Solution:-**

Copy **/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php**

to **/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php**

an change line number around 1016 in **magento 1.9** another search "if ($query)"

```
if ($query) {
    $mark = (strpos($url, '?') === false) ? '?' : ($escapeQuery ? '&amp;' : '&');
    $url .= $mark . $query;
}
```

To replace

```
//if ($query) {
if ($query && strpos($query, 'catalog_category') === false ) {
    $mark = (strpos($url, '?') === false) ? '?' : ($escapeQuery ? '&amp;' : '&');
    $url .= $mark . $query;
}
```

OR

```
if (!$query) {
        $mark = (strpos($url, '?') === false) ? '?' : ($escapeQuery ? '&amp;' : '&');
        $url .= $mark . $query;
    }
```

Now Flush Magento Cache and refresh page